# Redshift : Data migration

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need to migrate tables between two redshift environment (production to staging or vice versa) .Both of the environments are physically different location . Is there any utility that can be available for this .I don't want to use ETL tool .
So far I have tried to use unload into csv and load but its not quite fast as expected .
I need to automate this activity too . Please suggest the best possible approach.

Comment: Have you ever tried Redshift snapshots? You can restore even tables only from a snapshot. Since making a snapshot doesn't take too long, it would be appropriate for you. Check this for the details.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html

Comment: How is the throughput , will it be able to handle parallel migration with multiple threads ?

Comment: You say you are using unload and this is slow, are you unloading to s3 or somewhere else?

Comment: @JonScott I am unloading it to s3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two ways to export data from Amazon Redshift:

- Use the `UNLOAD` command to save a CSV file to Amazon S3
- Create a **snapshot** of the Amazon Redshift cluster

It is now possible to [Restoring a Table from a Snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html), so you could snapshot the entire cluster and then restore the desired table to another cluster.

The documentation says:

> You can **restore a single table** from a snapshot instead of restoring an entire cluster. When you restore a single table from a snapshot, you specify the source snapshot, database, schema, and table name, and the **target cluster, schema, and a new table name** for the restored table.

You should test the process to determine the speed of restoration.

The process can be automated by using the `aws redshift restore-table-from-cluster-snapshot` command in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).